# There is no hashHistory in the react-router module

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router

The hashHistory was not found in the react-router module. If I use react-router-dom then:

```
<HashRouter>
 <Route path = "/" Component = {App} />
</ HashRouter>,
document.getElementById ('root')
```

Displays an empty App.js window:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class App extends Component {
 render () {
  return (
   <div>
    <h1> Hello World! </ h1>
   </ div>
  );
 }
};
```

export default App;

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm not sure what you are asking here - are there errors in the console?

Comment: No error, white display, but i have code "<h1>Hello!</h1>"

Comment: The code you have shown looks ok - maybe you can put it in a codepen for us to look at?